# Pipline behavior of Format-Table

Tags: powershell, evaluation

I have trouble to understand pipline behavior in powershell.

I want to output a table which grows at every return in my script. Of course this works with `MyFunction | Format-Table` but I want to set the width. But this works only in the PowerShell ISE.

- PowerShell ISE: **output at every return of Main**
- PowerShell: **returns all output at the end**

*PowerShell Code:*

```
MyFunction | Format-Table @{Label="Prop1"; Expression={$_.Prop1};Width=10},  
                    @{Label="Prop2"; Expression={$_.Prop2};Width=14},  
                    @{Label="Prop3"; Expression={$_.Prop3};Width=10}
```

- PowerShell ISE: output at every return of Main
- PowerShell: output at every return of Main

*PowerShell Code:*

```
MyFunction | Format-Table
```

- PowerShell ISE: returns all output at the end
- PowerShell: returns all output at the end

*PowerShell Code:*

```
MyFunction | Format-Table -AutoSizre
```

Full Sample

```
function MyFunction
{
    $urls = "http://google.com", "http://theverge.com", "http://amazon.com", "http://wikipedia.org"

    foreach ($url in $urls)
    {
        $post = New-Object System.Object

        $perf = Measure-Command -Expression {
            try
            {
                $proxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy([uri]("http://google.com"))
                $post = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Proxy $proxy -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials
            }
            catch
            {
                $post | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name StatusCode -Value "Error"
            }
        }

        $post | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Url -Value $url
        $post
    }
}

MyFunction | ft Url, StatusCode, RawContentLength
```

Comment: This is not very clear. What is `Main`? Where is the rest of the script?

Comment: @arco444 just a function, in this case a few 'Invoke-WebRequest'

Comment: Can you add it to the question? The way it outputs its data is probably related to the issues you're experiencing

Comment: @user1776231 `Invoke-WebRequest` is asynchronous, and I couldn't reproduce the problem with a synchronous function. Maybe look into `Invoke-WebRequest` behavior instead?

Comment: @Vesper yes it is asynchronous and i want an asynchronous output. With -AutoSize is doesn't obviously work. But with fixed table widths it should work.